# How we can find out iPad orientation in SwiftUI, automatically getting notification or get update with a function?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-environment

I want to get notified when user changes iPad orientation. In UIKit that was easy but I do not know how we can get that information with SwiftUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation.isLandscape ?? false
```

or:

```
UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape
```

If you want to detect notifications you can listen to `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification`:

```
UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
...
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { ... }
```

---

Here is a demo:

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    init() {
        UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Text("Test")
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)) { _ in
                    print(UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation.isLandscape ?? false)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Omid It works for me without changing the orientation (Xcode 12.0.1).

Comment: @Omid Added a demo to my answer.

Comment: @Omid Works for me with `UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape` as well. You may try to add `UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()`

Comment: @Omid This is not a notification - please see my updated demo.

Comment: @Omid Worst case your app will crash. But there is no need to unwrap it. If it's nil then you won't be detecting the orientation change.

Comment: @Omid `??` is not force unwrapping, it will not crash the application if used on `nil` (unlike `!`). My recommendation: never force unwrap. Use `if`, `guard let`, `if let` etc. See [What is the nil coalescing operator?](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-the-nil-coalescing-operator)